# Add program to the application launcher widget in KDE plasma desktop for Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, kde

I would like to add Ipython qtconsole (for Python3) to the application launcher in the bottom panel at the KDE plasma desktop. I currently have three applications in the launcher:

- chromium browser
- Ipython qtconsole (Python2)
- konsole

Se below screen shot:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot remember how I added these applications in the first place. Now I would like to add Ipython qtconsole. If I right-click on the konsole icon in the laucher it pops up a menu with to items `Icon settings` and `Panel options`, but none of these sub menues allows me to modify the application launcher.

(The path to Ipython qtconsole is `/usr/bin/ipython3`.)

Answer (score 7):

**The KDE 4 default launcher**

As default the KDE 4 is using the Kickoff: https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff

More KDE application launchers: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59851-KDE-Application-Launchers

**Launcher button to the Panel - two ways**

1) Right click the application in the KDE Menu (default application launcher) >  Add to Panel.

[image]

Note ! Unlock the Widgets to get the 'Add to' options.

2) or right click the task manager application icon (in this Konsole icon) > Show A Launcher When not Running

[image]

**If the application is not in KDE Menu**

Right click the KDE Menu button > Edit Applications

[image]

Add the application to the KDE menu.

The KDE Menu Editor Handbook:

Right click the KDE Menu button > Edit Applications > Help > KDE Menu Editor Handbook

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to complete step 1. Which KDE-menu are you referring to?

Comment: For step 2: If I right-click the blue KDE icon in the lower-left of the screen, I get a pop-up menu with `Edit applications` as one of the items. If I choose this item, the KDE menu editor window appears and I can go down to the `Utilities` icon in the left panel, and click the arrow in front of it to get a list of utilities. From this list I can select `IPython3 Qt console`. If I do this I can check the `Place in system tray` button in the right panel. And then choose the `Save` button. But after this, still no icon appears in the system tray..

Comment: "Edit Applications..." helped. I needed to add a script.